# Create an ics file which is accepted by Outlook

Tags: java, outlook, icalendar

I am exposing some data from an app using an ics file, which is generated from java on the fly.

The ics validates fine here: https://icalendar.org/validator.html

My iPhone is happy with it - it shows all data and updates seamlessly

However I get problems with Outlook (desktop) and outlook.com.
On the desktop, the ics is accepted and the subscription set up OK. All events show and it even updates when they are changed. However if I exit Outlook and restart, the calendar shows for a second and then disappears. It is no longer in the calendars view on the left side and I have to remove the entry in "Account Settings" - "Internet Calendars" to be able to resubscribe.
On outlook.com, the calendar subscription is set up OK, but it never updates

Given that the ics validates OK, I imagine the problem is the way in which it is delivered, but I am running out of things to try

I am subscribing using webcal:// and the response headers are:

```
 content-disposition: attachment;filename="cal.ics" 
 content-length: 2462 
 content-type: text/calendar;method=REQUEST;name="cal.ics";charset=utf-8 
 date: Thu,30 Sep 2021 12:51:52 GMT
```

The headers may be a mess, because I tried so many things, so I'm open to ideas

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to publish a calendar.  In which case, use
METHOD=PUBLISH

See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2446#section-3.2.1

METHOD=REQUEST is for scheduling requests and similar

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it makes no difference